# Unable to install yo - with Node V8 and V10 - Error - x yo version

Tags: sharepoint, yeoman, spfx

I found a bug trying to install Yeoman Generator ( npm install yo --global) , but only with Node V8 and V10 and I only manage to install when a use the version V14.

My current SPFX solution is using SPFX 1.10 and have compatibility with v8 and v10.

I used all the possible solutions in this link : https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/591

Anyone know possible problems between node version (v8 and v10) with the lastest version of Yeoman?

Solve the problem of install yeoman

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLlK.png)

[Erro Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuEGx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this using node 10.24.1.

I was able to eliminate the error by using a previous version of yo. Run the following command

```
npm i -g yo@3
```

Hope this helps,
Don

Good luck!Don

---

If my answer helps solve or resolve your issue, please consider clicking **Mark as Best Response** & **Like**. This will help others to find the correct solution easily. It also closes the item. If the post was useful in other ways, please consider giving it a **Like**.

Comment: No yet. I followed the steps : 1-Install Node JS 10.24.1 | 2-Run 'npm install gulp-cli --global' | 3- And run 'npm i -g yo@3' .

Comment: Returned error: "{ Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "yo "--version""

Comment: Error Image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLlK.png
Error Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuEGx.png